# How do output each of the numbers in this sequence on its own line?

Tags: bash, shell, loops

I'm new to programming in general and my teacher is starting me out with simple bash scripts. 
This is what I did, but it's not working.

```
seq 1 3 | while read a; do
    echo 123
done
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Probably `echo $a` to see every number in `seq`, once per iteration?

Comment: This is what I wanted can you post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I posted it and you accepted the other :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `echo` command is the problem.  The example should look like

```
seq 1 3 | while read a; do
    echo $a
done
```

Rather than attempting to print all of the sequence values in each use of `echo`, you should be printing the individual sequence values read via the pipe from `seq`.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in comments, what you want to do is to use the output of `seq`, every time one.

Thus, use `echo "$a"` (good to quote!):

```
seq 1 3 | while read a; do
    echo "$a"
done
```

By the way, for safety it is good to use `IFS=` (input field separator) and `-r` for the read to prevent weird situations. Also, you can avoid the pipe by giving the input from indirection `< <(seq...)`. Finally, `seq 1 3` is the same as `seq 3`, since `1` is the default beginning point. All together:

```
while IFS= read -r a
do
echo "$a"
done < <(seq 3)
```

Comment: There is no need to surround the variable in quotations in this case as the domain is known and doesn't require it. The OP has also indicated that she is new to programming and you're introducing advanced concepts such as IFS and process substitution. Both of these things are irrelevant and add unnecessary complexity to an otherwise simple question.

Comment: Yeah, and in this case he could also have used `echo 1`, `echo 2` and `echo 3`. But since it is likely to be a very little initial example that then will be expanded, it is good to introduce the possible problems and avoid the OP guessing why isn't it working for a broader case. Learn not to quote variables and you will definitely encounter big problems! I don't think they are neither irrelevant neither unnecessary. And since I know the OP is just a beginng, I put them after the basic solution, not in place of it.

Comment: Sometimes it's better to keep it simple with beginners. Too much information too quickly can lead to confusion. Keep it simple, especially when introducing new concepts. The basics which are second nature to us are HARD for beginners. Keep it brief and to the point. Keep it simple. Keep it sweet.

Comment: @Zhro we agree. I will say that answers are not for one time and one person, but for posterity and everybody: thus, a broader approach will lead to different people getting different levels of knowledge out of it.